# Unity Photon Fusion Object Position Sync

Tags: unity-game-engine, fusion

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP9nM.png)
Photon Fusion How to sync Object Position?

```cs
public class PlayerTrigger : NetworkBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] NetworkCharacterControllerPrototype characterControllerPrototype;
    [SerializeField] NetworkTransform _root;
    [SerializeField] private float pushPower = 2.0f; // 박스를 밀 때의 힘
    NetworkRigidbody _rootBox;
    bool _isTele = false;
    bool _isPushBox = false;
    Rigidbody _pushedBody;
    [Networked]
    public Vector3 PushDirection { get; set; }


    public override void FixedUpdateNetwork()
    {
        base.FixedUpdateNetwork();

       
         
        if (_isPushBox && _pushedBody != null)
        {
            _pushedBody.velocity = PushDirection * pushPower;
            _isPushBox = false;
            _rootBox.FixedUpdateNetwork();
        }
        
    }

    private void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit)
    {

        if (hit.gameObject.tag == "MoveBox")
        {
            _pushedBody = hit.collider.attachedRigidbody;
            _rootBox = hit.gameObject.GetComponent<NetworkRigidbody>();
            // 박스에 Rigidbody가 없거나, Kinematic이면 무시
            if (_pushedBody == null || _pushedBody.isKinematic)
            {
                return;
            }
            // 박스를 밀어내는 방향 계산
            PushDirection = new Vector3(hit.moveDirection.x, 0, hit.moveDirection.z);
            _isPushBox = true; // 힘을 적용해야 함을 나타내는 플래그 설정
        }


    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("TeleBox"))
        {
            _isTele = true;
        }
    }


}
```

how to sync this?

this is my blog

https://gogogocoding.tistory.com/103
upload dont sync object video

i wanna sync this

and
base.FixedUpdateNetwork(); this state is keeping Or delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Just add NetworkTransform to your NetworkObject and it will be synchronized automatically.

Comment: that was a my first try.. i'm failed